# Setting payload for email using burp intruder

Tags: email, attacks, brute-force, audit, burp-suite

I am setting up the burp intruder attack for email. For example, `youremail@gmail.com`

Now when i added `$` it takes `youremail@gmail%2ecom`  so i am getting the result as email is invalid type.

My aim is to achieve `yoursemail@gmail.com` but it takes %2e.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Payloads" tab of Intruder, go to the bottom. There is a "Payload Encoding" section where you can specify which characters to URL-encode. You can remove the '.', or disable this feature completely.